# Definition of multiplier bialgebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, bialgebras, multiplier-algebra

Consider the following fragments from "An invitation to quantum groups and duality" by Timmerman:

[image]

**Question**: In remark 2.1.6 (ii), it is stated that the homomorphism $\Delta\otimes \text{id}: A \otimes A \to A \otimes A \otimes A$ is extended to a homomorphism $M(A \otimes A) \to M(A \otimes A \otimes A)$. However, don't we start from a homomorphism
$$\Delta \otimes \text{id}: A \otimes A \to M(A \otimes A) \otimes A$$
? If so, how does this extension work? One possibility I see is to embed $$M(A \otimes A)\otimes A \subseteq M(A \otimes A) \otimes M(A) \subseteq M(A \otimes A \otimes A)$$ and we then obtain a homomorphism
$$\Delta\otimes \text{id}: A \otimes A \to M(A \otimes A \otimes A)$$ which (probably) can be extended to a homomorphism
$$\Delta\otimes \text{id}: M(A \otimes A) \to M(A \otimes A \otimes A)$$

Are the observations I make in this post correct? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}\newcommand{\finite}{\text{fin}}$The answer is yes to both; all references are to Timmermann.

1. The map $M(A \otimes A) \otimes A \to M(A \otimes A \otimes A)$ is the composition of obvious inclusion $M(A \otimes A) \otimes A \hookrightarrow M(A \otimes A) \otimes M(A)$ with the natural embedding $$M(A \otimes A) \otimes M(A) \hookrightarrow M((A \otimes A) \otimes A) = M(A \otimes A \otimes A)$$ of Proposition 2.1.4, part v.
2. Once you’re satisfied that the composition
   $$
    A \otimes A \xrightarrow{\Delta \otimes \operatorname{id}} M(A \otimes A) \otimes A \hookrightarrow M(A \otimes A) \otimes M(A) \hookrightarrow M(A \otimes A \otimes A)
   $$
   is non-degenerate, it extends uniquely to a homomorphism $A \otimes A \to M(A \otimes A \otimes A)$ by Proposition 2.1.4, part vi.

---

Addendum on motivation:

It’s worth remembering just why multiplier algebras arise in noncommutative geometry—you can see why even at the most elementary, purely algebraic level.

Given a set $X$, let $\bC_\finite(X)$ denote the $\ast$-algebra of finitely supported functions $X \to \mathbb{C}$ with the usual pointwise operations. Let $\phi : X \to Y$ be a function. You’d like to define a $\ast$-homomorphism $\phi^t: \bC_\finite(Y) \to \bC_\finite(X)$ by
$$
 \forall a  \in \bC_\finite(Y), \quad \phi^t(a) := a \circ \phi.
$$
The moment that there exists $y \in Y$ such that $\phi^{-1}(y)$ is infinite, your would-be $\ast$-homomorphism $\phi^t$ fails to have the correct codomain, since any function $a \in \bC_\finite(Y)$ whose support contains $y$ will yield a function $\phi^t(a) : X \to \mathbb{C}$ with infinite support. However, even in this worst case scenario, $\phi^t(a)$ will still yield a multiplier of $\bC_\finite(X)$ acting via pointwise multiplication. Hence, no matter how badly behaved $\phi$ may be, we can always make sense of $\phi^t$ as a non-degenerate $\ast$-homomorphism
$$
 \phi^t: \bC_\finite(Y) \to \bC(X) \cong M(\bC_\finite(X)).
$$
In short, if you want $\mathbb{C}_{\mathrm{fin}}$ to define a contravariant functor from the category of sets and functions to some category of (not-necessarily unital) $\ast$-algebras, you need the codomain to be the category where objects are $\ast$-algebras and where a morphism from $A$ to $B$ is a non-degenerate $\ast$-homomorphism $f: A \to M(B)$; in the $C^\ast$-algebraic context, this insight is apparently due to Woronowicz (see this older [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82871/reference-request-for-translating-from-top-to-c-alg)).

So, what, then is the remark saying? It’s simply saying that the given definition of multiplier bialgebra is the obvious result of taking the definition of bialgebra from the category of unital $\ast$-algebras and unital $\ast$-homomorphisms and adapting it systematically to the above category of (not-necessarily unital) $\ast$-algebras by replacing any unital $\ast$-homomorphism $A \to B$ by a non-degenerate $\ast$-homomorphism $A \to M(B)$.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should delete your last answer, which was quite good also. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tacked it on as an addendum.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could upvote more than once.